# SSIS - SQL Server Agent Job not working properly

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssis

Before I start, unfortunately I do not have access to the package design as the person who created this package has left and was stored locally on his office computer. However, this package is called "GenericReportExtract", and, as you can probably gather, was designed to be a multipurpose SSIS package which creates an SSRS report and then emails an Excel version to the recipients the report was designed for.

This package has worked perfectly for every single Job it has been used by except one, where, for some reason, will say the Job has run without any errors, but when you look in the output path of this report, it doesn't exist.

But, when I run it manually (i.e. right click job > Start Job at Step), the report is actually produced and you can see it in the output path for the report.

The job itself was run under Admin\SQL_Services, so I thought it maybe didn't like the owner and I changed it to under my log-in, seeming as it worked fine when I manually ran it. However, the next time the job was scheduled to run, the recipient still didn't receive the report and still didn't appear in the output path.

I do not wish to create a new package as there are too many packages that rely on this package, and I suspect it's something to do with the job. It's worth noting that this job ran successfully for about a year until last Christmas, and  then in January it stopped doing what it was supposed to do, even though the Job history says it's working fine. I have been manually running the job since, but it does need attending to now.

Comment: How is the job set up? If its pointing at a .dtsx file you can just open that in BIDS. If it's pointing at a SQL Server package you can just export it out of SQL Server and open it in BIDS. How does the package know which report to export and where to export it to?

Comment: Have you [configured a proxy account](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/) and set that account as the Run As account in the SSIS step configuration?  What error message are you getting?  Does the proxy account have access to the file system or db mail (not sure entirely which you're using here)?  You could also try [importing the package into BIDS](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1428/import-export-copy-and-delete-ssis-packages/).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Well, when I look at Job Step properties, the type is SSIS Package, package source is SSIS Package Store, and the package is located in \File System\GenericReportExtract. But when I click the '...' button to see its location, it just says SSIS Package >  File System; MSDB. So I don't know where the package is located. The package looks at a table and selects the rows for a given package name, and then uses those rows as parameters for the package.

Comment: So it's stored in MSDB. If you want to take a look inside the package you need to connect to the SSIS service from within SSMS and export the package to the file system (as a .dtsx file) then you can open that in BIDS.  If you can open it in BIDS you have a chance to run it interactively and check. You could also use SQL Profiler to monitor queries on that table while the package is being run. Also, packages often have logging configured, though you'll only find out if you can open it in BIDS.